# ripple carry adder vs carry look ahead DELAY?

Tags: vivado

I have implemented 3 combinational circuits of adders (RCA, CLA and IP CORE, adder v.12) in a method to measure the power consumption in the FPGA, but the results in the delays are incoherent.
A ripple carry should be slower than a lookahead however in my results it is not appreciated. I have checked it for different size for the entries.
I leave an image, so you can give me your conclusions. 
Thanks for your help.

P.S. The delay I have taken from a circuit that implements a frequency of 25MHz, and I have taken calculations from the term WNS. (Implementation -> Report Timming)

25MHz = 40ns  -> DELAY= 40ns - WNS.

Vivado 2017.1

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Implementing logic on an FPGA is not at all like stringing together AND and OR gates. The FPGA implements logic using look-up tables, and many FPGAs have dedicated logic and wiring to create fast adders. This means that the way you write your HDL can have a huge effect, either positive or negative, on the timing results.

Changing the number of inputs and outputs will also change the placement of logic on the FPGA, which can have subtle and unexpected effects.

In other words, it probably doesn't make sense to try to extrapolate from your gate-level circuits to actual implementation on an FPGA.

Comment: Thanks for answering. But that is the only stage to measure delays at FPGA level, right?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean by "that is the only stage".

Comment: I mean that from the implementation process, the configuration of the FPGA is implemented. Then to measure the circuit dealy will be the only way.